# why does the laplacian operator detect the image edge?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection, laplacian

I know that the gradient (Gx,Gy) is to measure the largest change direction of image function G(x,y). Therefore, the edge detection is to find maximum points of Gx^2+Gy^2. Thus, what's the principle of Laplacian edge detection? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51414532/7328782

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, it is the zero-crossings of the Laplacian, which are used to detect edges. The Laplacian operator is a function of the second derivatives of the image. An edge is a local maximum of the first derivative, which is the point where the second derivative is zero.

Comment: In the case of dimension one, a local maximum of the first derivate is just the zeros of the second derivative. However, in dimesion 2, it's not  obvious. I  still do not understand why the crossing zeros of the Laplacian denote edge.