# Using Sobel operator with only 1D convolution

Tags: matlab, image-processing, convolution, sobel

The Sobel operator is using a separable kernel. That means that the Sobel operator can use 1D convolution vector multiplication instead of 2D convolution matrix multiplication. The 1D convolution vector multiplication requires less iteration compared to the 2D case.

Here is a working example how to do Sobel operation with `conv2`, assuming that `X` is a matrix of e.g a picture.

```
K_x = [-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1];
K_y = [-1 -2 -1; 0 0 0; 1 2 1];

% Do conv2
Gx = conv2(X, K_x, 'same');
Gy = conv2(X, K_y, 'same');

% Compute the gradients
G = sqrt(Gx.^2 + Gy.^2);

% Compute the orientations
O = atan2d(Gy, Gx);
```

**Question:**

How should the kernel look like if I want to use the 1D `conv` command to compute the Sobel operator in Matlab?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question: are you asking how to separate `K_x`  (or `K_y`) as a product of a column vector and a row vector? If so: `K_x` equals `[1; 2; 1].*[-1 0 1]`, and similarly for `K_y`

Comment: For a 3x3 kernel, separating it usually does not make it faster. You go from 9 multiplications and additions to 6, but you also need to loop over the image twice, and here memory access will usually be more expensive than those 3 multiplications and additions that you save. But it can be convenient to implement that way, if you already have code for the separable convolution but not the full convolution.

Comment: @CrisLuengo so this method is less effective?

Comment: this does not involve matrix multiplication. it's *element-wise* multiplication.

Comment: I’ve written a blog post collecting a lot of the stuff we’ve been talking about in comments on SO. Maybe it helps seeing it all in a more logical order. https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/1142/

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have read your post. I like it. I understand that the filters is like an ODE, but can you show us an example with a basic simulation of a for-loop for FIR and IIR filter in Matlab? That would help, because then I can expriment with some values and see diffrent results. I also understand that the direct method is not FIR nor IIR.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Is this an example for FIR-filtering for 1D convolution? https://pastebin.com/LrnfZqrY It only contains 2 for-loops. I don't think I can optimize more than this.

Comment: @CrisLuengo By the way! I have found that `laplacian` 1D kernel is much better to use for 2D convolution, rather than `sobel`, even if them both are `3x3` kernels. The purpose is edge detection.

Comment: @euraad The Laplacian is not an edge detector: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51414532/7328782

Comment: @euraad Looking at your pastebin, `a1[j] * k[j]` is not a convolution. Each output value is exactly the same! Note the convolution sum is defined as `a1[i-j] * k[j]`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, but I shift the index of `a1` as well, instead of doing `a1[i-j]`. I have tried this code with Matlab and it gives the same result.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Laplacian can be used as an edge detection. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIrwQ3N2WcM&ab_channel=KnowledgeAmplifier `h = fspecial('laplacian') ` returns a `3x3` matrix that are separable

Comment: @euraad That is a common misconception. It detects lines, not edges. It does have a response to edges, but is 0 on the edge, and so not an edge detector. You can build an edge detector by finding the zero crossings of the Laplace. But the Laplace itself is not an edge detector. This is taught wrongly in many image processing courses, unfortunately. Also, the Laplacian kernel is not separable, it cannot be written as the product of two 1D kernels (it’s the sum).

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did not know that the laplacian `3x3` kernel is not separable. Can you recommend the fastest edge detector? Can it be `Sobel`?

Comment: If it has to be as fast as possible, use Sobel. Better detectors all have larger kernels.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you. Speed is important here because I don't actually care about how "good" the result becomes. The only important for me is to get some edges of an object.